# Already installed Python module undetected when running Python script. 'tdqm'

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-module, kali-linux

'tdqm' module not found even though it is installed.

I have a Python script containing the line `from tdqm import tdqm`, but when I try to run using the command `python3 script.py`, it returns back the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/Downloads/folder/script.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tdqm import tdqm
```

I used `pip show tdqm` command with all the installed Python versions on my machine and they all detect the module, giving the output:

```
Name: tdqm
Version: 0.0.1
Summary: Alias for typos of tqdm
Home-page: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: MPLv2.0
Location: /home/username/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: tqdm
Required-by:
```

When I try to install it again using the command `pip3 install tdqm`, I get the message:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: tdqm in /home/username/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from tdqm) (4.64.1)
```

I also tried uninstalling and installing it again with different versions of pip, but it still didn't work.

I can find the module in the specified path, and I tried running the script as my user as well as as the root user.

I am working on kali linux and I couldn't find a solution to this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is called [`tqdm`](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/), not `tdqm`.

However there is a package called [`tdqm`](https://pypi.org/project/tdqm/) that simply depends on the proper package:

> Alias for typos of [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm).

Typing it wrong should work when *installing*, but when you *use it* you'll have to spell it correctly:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
```